# upload a maven assembly jar to nexus and use it in gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, jar, nexus

I am trying to upload a jar file to nexus so that I can provide it's dependency in my other project and use the classes and functionality it provides. It is the same as using a dependency from maven or gradle. 
I have successful in uploading the jar file to nexus with it's pom and following is the command I used to do so:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=<path-to-pom> \
-Dfile=<path-to-file> \
-DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
-Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>
```

I was also able to pull the repository from nexus using the following gradle configurations:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "<url to maven releases>"
    }
}

dependencies {
  compile("test-app:test-app:1.0")
}
```

I was able to run the gradlew clean build successfully but somehow when I try to run the application, I am getting the error that 'cannot find symbol' for the classes from the test-app dependency

Comment: Looks alright to me. I guess the error might be in the pom you uploaded or generally, in the version of the artifact you are using.

Comment: Yes, got it working. The only change I added was adding credentials to the maven tag in build.gradle. After that all worked.